# How do I find $P(X ≤ 1)$ given $P(X ≥ 0)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

So I have been given this example in my notes:

The continuous random variable $X$ has a pdf defined by:

\begin{eqnarray} f(x) & = & k(9-x)^2 & \mbox{for } -3 \leq X \leq 3 \\
 & = & 0\ & \mbox{otherwise.}
\end{eqnarray}

The example asks to find $P(X \leq 1)$ given $P(X \geq 0)$ and shows part of the working out as:
$$ P(X \leq 1 \; | \; X \geq 0)={P(0 \leq X \leq 1) \over P(X \geq 0)}$$

My question is, how does the left side equal the right side of the equation? I assume that the equation: $P(A|B) = {P(A\cap B) \over P(B)}$ is used, but then I can't understand how $P(A\cap B)$ equals $0 \leq X \leq 1$?

Comment: I imagine that should read $P(0 \leq X \leq 1)$ on the numerator?

Comment: It should have read that on the numerator. I fixed it now.

Comment: $P(X\leq 1 \cap X\geq 0)=P(0\leq X\leq 1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the events $A=\{\omega\,\colon\ X(\omega)\leq 1\}$ and $B=\{\omega\,\colon\ X(\omega)\geq 0\}$. Then
$$
A\cap B
=\{\omega\,\colon\ X(\omega)\leq 1 \,\text{and} \,X(\omega)\geq 0\}
=\{\omega\,\colon\ 0\leq X(\omega)\leq 1\}
$$
So $P(A\cap B)=P(0\leq X\leq 1)$.